# cy.visit() fails because of content-type issue

Tags: cypress

cy.visit() method fails because of the below issue can someone help me to fix this issue, please?

[image]

I am just using this method:

```
visit() {
  cy.visit('/',{failOnStatusCode: false})
}
```

Comment: Seems like you're visiting an API endpoint instead of a web page

Comment: No its a web page. Can navigate to the web page by browser

Answer (score -1):

Cypress's `visit` function is intended only for fetching and processing web**pages**. Thus, it [requires](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#Requirements) the response to be `content-type: text/html`, so that it can parse and display it.

For validating other things, like endpoints, plain files (e.g. a link to a PDF or video), or any case where you only need to check for a valid response (`2xx` or `3xx`) you should use [request()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request). As a bonus, it's also much faster.

So there are two possibilities:

1. Your link is actually an endpoint or file and thus you should use `request`
2. Your server is misconfigured and returning the wrong `content-type` for the link